# how does these vertices end up in clip coordinate(-1,1)?

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl, webgl2

Hi guys I been learning webGl these days and reading this textbook on webGl2.

Here is an example out of this book.

```js
'use strict';

// A set of utility functions for /common operations across our application
const utils = {

  // Find and return a DOM element given an ID
  getCanvas(id) {
    const canvas = document.getElementById(id);

    if (!canvas) {
      console.error(`There is no canvas with id ${id} on this page.`);
      return null;
    }

    return canvas;
  },

  // Given a canvas element, return the WebGL2 context
  getGLContext(canvas) {
    return canvas.getContext('webgl2') || console.error('WebGL2 is not available in your browser.');
  },

  // Given a canvas element, expand it to the size of the window
  // and ensure that it automatically resizes as the window changes
  autoResizeCanvas(canvas) {
    const expandFullScreen = () => {
      canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
      canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    };
    expandFullScreen();
    // Resize screen when the browser has triggered the resize event
    window.addEventListener('resize', expandFullScreen);
  },

  // Given a WebGL context and an id for a shader script,
  // return a compiled shader
  getShader(gl, id) {
    const script = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!script) {
      return null;
    }

    const shaderString = script.text.trim();

    let shader;
    if (script.type === 'x-shader/x-vertex') {
      shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    } else if (script.type === 'x-shader/x-fragment') {
      shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    } else {
      return null;
    }

    gl.shaderSource(shader, shaderString);
    gl.compileShader(shader);

    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      console.error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
      return null;
    }

    return shader;
  },

  // Normalize colors from 0-255 to 0-1
  normalizeColor(color) {
    return color.map(c => c / 255);
  },

  // De-normalize colors from 0-1 to 0-255
  denormalizeColor(color) {
    return color.map(c => c * 255);
  },

  // Returns computed normals for provided vertices.
  // Note: Indices have to be completely defined--NO TRIANGLE_STRIP only TRIANGLES.
  calculateNormals(vs, ind) {
    const
      x = 0,
      y = 1,
      z = 2,
      ns = [];

    // For each vertex, initialize normal x, normal y, normal z
    for (let i = 0; i < vs.length; i += 3) {
      ns[i + x] = 0.0;
      ns[i + y] = 0.0;
      ns[i + z] = 0.0;
    }

    // We work on triads of vertices to calculate
    for (let i = 0; i < ind.length; i += 3) {
      // Normals so i = i+3 (i = indices index)
      const v1 = [],
        v2 = [],
        normal = [];

      // p2 - p1
      v1[x] = vs[3 * ind[i + 2] + x] - vs[3 * ind[i + 1] + x];
      v1[y] = vs[3 * ind[i + 2] + y] - vs[3 * ind[i + 1] + y];
      v1[z] = vs[3 * ind[i + 2] + z] - vs[3 * ind[i + 1] + z];

      // p0 - p1
      v2[x] = vs[3 * ind[i] + x] - vs[3 * ind[i + 1] + x];
      v2[y] = vs[3 * ind[i] + y] - vs[3 * ind[i + 1] + y];
      v2[z] = vs[3 * ind[i] + z] - vs[3 * ind[i + 1] + z];

      // Cross product by Sarrus Rule
      normal[x] = v1[y] * v2[z] - v1[z] * v2[y];
      normal[y] = v1[z] * v2[x] - v1[x] * v2[z];
      normal[z] = v1[x] * v2[y] - v1[y] * v2[x];

      // Update the normals of that triangle: sum of vectors
      for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        ns[3 * ind[i + j] + x] = ns[3 * ind[i + j] + x] + normal[x];
        ns[3 * ind[i + j] + y] = ns[3 * ind[i + j] + y] + normal[y];
        ns[3 * ind[i + j] + z] = ns[3 * ind[i + j] + z] + normal[z];
      }
    }

    // Normalize the result.
    // The increment here is because each vertex occurs.
    for (let i = 0; i < vs.length; i += 3) {
      // With an offset of 3 in the array (due to x, y, z contiguous values)
      const nn = [];
      nn[x] = ns[i + x];
      nn[y] = ns[i + y];
      nn[z] = ns[i + z];

      let len = Math.sqrt((nn[x] * nn[x]) + (nn[y] * nn[y]) + (nn[z] * nn[z]));
      if (len === 0) len = 1.0;

      nn[x] = nn[x] / len;
      nn[y] = nn[y] / len;
      nn[z] = nn[z] / len;

      ns[i + x] = nn[x];
      ns[i + y] = nn[y];
      ns[i + z] = nn[z];
    }

    return ns;
  },

  // A simpler API on top of the dat.GUI API, specifically
  // designed for this book for a simpler codebase
  configureControls(settings, options = {
    width: 300
  }) {
    // Check if a gui instance is passed in or create one by default
    const gui = options.gui || new dat.GUI(options);
    const state = {};

    const isAction = v => typeof v === 'function';

    const isFolder = v =>
      !isAction(v) &&
      typeof v === 'object' &&
      (v.value === null || v.value === undefined);

    const isColor = v =>
      (typeof v === 'string' && ~v.indexOf('#')) ||
      (Array.isArray(v) && v.length >= 3);

    Object.keys(settings).forEach(key => {
      const settingValue = settings[key];

      if (isAction(settingValue)) {
        state[key] = settingValue;
        return gui.add(state, key);
      }
      if (isFolder(settingValue)) {
        // If it's a folder, recursively call with folder as root settings element
        return utils.configureControls(settingValue, {
          gui: gui.addFolder(key)
        });
      }

      const {
        value,
        min,
        max,
        step,
        options,
        onChange = () => null,
      } = settingValue;

      // set state
      state[key] = value;

      let controller;

      // There are many other values we can set on top of the dat.GUI
      // API, but we'll only need a few for our purposes
      if (options) {
        controller = gui.add(state, key, options);
      } else if (isColor(value)) {
        controller = gui.addColor(state, key)
      } else {
        controller = gui.add(state, key, min, max, step)
      }

      controller.onChange(v => onChange(v, state))
    });
  },

  // Calculate tangets for a given set of vertices
  calculateTangents(vs, tc, ind) {
    const tangents = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < vs.length / 3; i++) {
      tangents[i] = [0, 0, 0];
    }

    let
      a = [0, 0, 0],
      b = [0, 0, 0],
      triTangent = [0, 0, 0];

    for (let i = 0; i < ind.length; i += 3) {
      const i0 = ind[i];
      const i1 = ind[i + 1];
      const i2 = ind[i + 2];

      const pos0 = [vs[i0 * 3], vs[i0 * 3 + 1], vs[i0 * 3 + 2]];
      const pos1 = [vs[i1 * 3], vs[i1 * 3 + 1], vs[i1 * 3 + 2]];
      const pos2 = [vs[i2 * 3], vs[i2 * 3 + 1], vs[i2 * 3 + 2]];

      const tex0 = [tc[i0 * 2], tc[i0 * 2 + 1]];
      const tex1 = [tc[i1 * 2], tc[i1 * 2 + 1]];
      const tex2 = [tc[i2 * 2], tc[i2 * 2 + 1]];

      vec3.subtract(a, pos1, pos0);
      vec3.subtract(b, pos2, pos0);

      const c2c1b = tex1[1] - tex0[1];
      const c3c1b = tex2[0] - tex0[1];

      triTangent = [c3c1b * a[0] - c2c1b * b[0], c3c1b * a[1] - c2c1b * b[1], c3c1b * a[2] - c2c1b * b[2]];

      vec3.add(triTangent, tangents[i0], triTangent);
      vec3.add(triTangent, tangents[i1], triTangent);
      vec3.add(triTangent, tangents[i2], triTangent);
    }

    // Normalize tangents
    const ts = [];
    tangents.forEach(tan => {
      vec3.normalize(tan, tan);
      ts.push(tan[0]);
      ts.push(tan[1]);
      ts.push(tan[2]);
    });

    return ts;
  }

};


'use strict';

let
  gl,
  program,
  vao,
  indices,
  indicesBuffer,
  modelViewMatrix = mat4.create(),
  projectionMatrix = mat4.create(),
  normalMatrix = mat4.create();

function initProgram() {
  // Configure `canvas`
  const canvas = utils.getCanvas('webgl-canvas');
  utils.autoResizeCanvas(canvas);

  // Configure `gl`
  gl = utils.getGLContext(canvas);
  gl.clearColor(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1);
  gl.clearDepth(100);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);

  // Shader source
  const vertexShader = utils.getShader(gl, 'vertex-shader');
  const fragmentShader = utils.getShader(gl, 'fragment-shader');

  // Configure `program`
  program = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(program);

  if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    console.error('Could not initialize shaders');
  }

  gl.useProgram(program);

  // Set locations onto `program` instance
  program.aVertexPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'aVertexPosition');
  program.aVertexNormal = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'aVertexNormal');
  program.uProjectionMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uProjectionMatrix');
  program.uModelViewMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uModelViewMatrix');
  program.uNormalMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uNormalMatrix');
  program.uLightDirection = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uLightDirection');
  program.uLightAmbient = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uLightAmbient');
  program.uLightDiffuse = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uLightDiffuse');
  program.uMaterialDiffuse = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uMaterialDiffuse');
}

// Configure lights
function initLights() {
  gl.uniform3fv(program.uLightDirection, [0, 0, -1]);
  gl.uniform4fv(program.uLightAmbient, [0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 1]);
  gl.uniform4fv(program.uLightDiffuse, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1]);
  gl.uniform4f(program.uMaterialDiffuse, 0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 1);
}

/**
 * This function generates the example data and create the buffers
 *
 *           4          5             6         7
 *           +----------+-------------+---------+
 *           |          |             |         |
 *           |          |             |         |
 *           |          |             |         |
 *           |          |             |         |
 *           |          |             |         |
 *           +----------+-------------+---------+
 *           0          1             2         3
 *
 */
function initBuffers() {
  const vertices = [-20, -8, 20, // 0
    -10, -8, 0, // 1
    10, -8, 0, // 2
    20, -8, 20, // 3
    -20, 8, 20, // 4
    -10, 8, 0, // 5
    10, 8, 0, // 6
    20, 8, 20 // 7
  ];

  indices = [
    0, 5, 4,
    1, 5, 0,
    1, 6, 5,
    2, 6, 1,
    2, 7, 6,
    3, 7, 2
  ];

  // Create VAO
  vao = gl.createVertexArray();

  // Bind Vao
  gl.bindVertexArray(vao);

  const normals = utils.calculateNormals(vertices, indices);

  const verticesBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  //console.log('vertices', vertices);
  // Configure instructions
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.aVertexPosition);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.aVertexPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  const normalsBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, normalsBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(normals), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  // Configure instructions
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.aVertexNormal);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.aVertexNormal, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  indicesBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  // Clean
  gl.bindVertexArray(null);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
}

function draw() {
  const {
    width,
    height
  } = gl.canvas;

  gl.viewport(0, 0, width, height);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  mat4.perspective(projectionMatrix, 45, width / height, 0.1, 10000);
  mat4.identity(modelViewMatrix);
  mat4.translate(modelViewMatrix, modelViewMatrix, [0, 0, -40]);

  mat4.copy(normalMatrix, modelViewMatrix);
  mat4.invert(normalMatrix, normalMatrix);
  mat4.transpose(normalMatrix, normalMatrix);

  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(program.uModelViewMatrix, false, modelViewMatrix);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(program.uProjectionMatrix, false, projectionMatrix);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(program.uNormalMatrix, false, normalMatrix);

  // We will start using the `try/catch` to capture any errors from our `draw` calls
  try {
    // Bind
    gl.bindVertexArray(vao);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesBuffer);

    // Draw
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    // Clean
    gl.bindVertexArray(null);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
  }
  // We catch the `error` and simply output to the screen for testing/debugging purposes
  catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  draw();
}

function init() {
  initProgram();
  initBuffers();
  initLights();
  render();
}

init();
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.4.0/gl-matrix.js"></script>

  <!-- modules -->

  <!-- vertex Shader -->
  <script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
  #version 300 es
    precision mediump float;

    uniform mat4 uModelViewMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uNormalMatrix;
    uniform vec3 uLightDirection;
    uniform vec4 uLightAmbient;
    uniform vec4 uLightDiffuse;
    uniform vec4 uMaterialDiffuse;

    in vec3 aVertexPosition;
    in vec3 aVertexNormal;

    out vec4 vVertexColor;

    void main(void) {
      vec3 N = vec3(uNormalMatrix * vec4(aVertexNormal, 1.0));
      vec3 L = normalize(uLightDirection);
      float lambertTerm = dot(N, -L);

      // Ambient
      vec4 Ia = uLightAmbient;
      // Diffuse
      vec4 Id = uMaterialDiffuse * uLightDiffuse * lambertTerm;

      // Set varying to be used inside of fragment shader
      vVertexColor = vec4(vec3(Ia + Id), 1.0);
      gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * uModelViewMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
    }
  </script>

  <!-- fragment Shader -->
  <script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    #version 300 es
    precision mediump float;

    in vec4 vVertexColor;

    out vec4 fragColor;

    void main(void)  {
      fragColor = vVertexColor;
    }
  </script>
  <canvas id="webgl-canvas"></canvas>
```

here the vertices are defined as

```
const vertices = [
        -20, -8, 20, // 0
        -10, -8, 0,  // 1
        10, -8, 0,   // 2
        20, -8, 20,  // 3
        -20, 8, 20,  // 4
        -10, 8, 0,   // 5
        10, 8, 0,    // 6
        20, 8, 20    // 7
      ];
```

As I've learned that webGl use `clipspace coordinates`, which goes from -1 to +1. However here these vertices are out of this range.

Could someone please point me to the code where it transforms these vertices to `clipspace coordinates`? I've been looking at the code for a while but cannot seem to find it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider reading these lessons on WebGL. [Here are some that explain clipspace](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-fundamentals.html) and here is one that explains [how to use matrices to convert from some space to clipspace using matrix math](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrices.html) and here is one that explains [how convert from 3D space to clipspace with matrix math](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-orthographic.html) and one that explains [how to get perspective with matrix math](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-perspective.html) and this one that explains [how cameras work with a view matrix](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-camera.html)

In answer to your question this line in the vertex shader

```
  gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * uModelViewMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
```

converts from those vertices into clip space by choosing the correct matrices to assign `uProjectionMatrix` and `uModelViewMatrix`. `uModelViewMatrix` positions, scales, and orients the model in view space. `uProjectionMatrix` then converts from view space to clip space with a perspective projection.